# C++ Unix and Windows support

Tags: c++, windows, unix, cross-platform

I want to make my project available for Linux.
Therefore, I need to substitute functions from windows.h library.

In my terminal.cpp I highlight error messages in red. This step I only want to do in windows OS (ANSI don't work for my console, so i don't have a cross-platform solution for this).

On windows it works, but on Linux i get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvTgiE8.o: in function `SetConsoleTextAttribute(int, int)':
Terminal.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `SetConsoleTextAttribute(int, int)'; /tmp/cclUawx7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my main.cpp file I do nothing but include terminal.h and run it.

terminal.cpp

```
if (OS_Windows)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(dependency.hConsole, 4);
    cout << "Error: " << e.getMessage() << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(dependency.hConsole, 7);
}
else
{
    cout << "Error: " << e.getMessage() << endl;
}
```

terminal.h

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define OS_Windows 1
#include "WindowsDependency.h"
#else
#define OS_Windows 0
#include "UnixDependency.h"
#endif
```

WindowsDependency.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

class Dependency
{
public:
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
};
```

UnixDependency.h

```
#pragma once
class Dependency
{
public:
    int hConsole = 0;
};

void SetConsoleTextAttribute(int hConsole, int second) {};
```

Comment: You need to use the precompiler's `#ifdef` or `#if` when writing cross platform/compiler code, eg: `#if (OS_Windows==1) /* windows code... */ #else /* non-windows code... #endif` The compiler's `if` will not work the way you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files are supposed to contain *declarations*. By adding the `{}` you made a `definition` and C++ does not allow multiple definitions of the same function with identical signatures.

Either remove the `{}` and provide a *definition* in a separately-compiled .cpp file, OR by marking the function as `inline`.

Comment: Good catch. I misremembered. C++17 introduces support for inline _variables_.